# MYSQL query giving me syntax error when correct in Node.JS?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I wrote a big query and tested in my sql program and successful got a row inserted. In Node, I basically converted this query to a string and ran it so I could insert the data from my server.

It seems like I've been able to nail the problem to the variable assignments using the @ symbol. Not sure why this is deemed as invalid syntax, though?

[Node Code Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djO5N.png)

I printed out exactly what I fed into my Node function and copied it into my SQL program to run the command. It worked.

[Printed Terminal Output for Query String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOA8F.png)

## Error

```
{ [Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @UNIX_DAY=86400; SET @UNIX_WEEK =    604800; SET @INITIAL_TRANSACTION_TIME = 14' at line 1] code: 1064 }
```

This query string that I fed in is confirmed working, but when I execute the query in Node, I get a syntax error. What could this be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mysql command line client splits multiple queries on the delimiter, which defaults to `;` and sends them to the server individually.

Your code needs to send them to the server as the separate queries that they actually are, although all the `SET` queries can be combined together, `SET @a = 1, @b = 2, @c = 3;` etc.  But the `INSERT` is still a separate query.

Some client libraries can support the ability to send multiple queries like this but you do not want that. It represents a massive security vulnerability.